# uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on a datalayer push

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

I got this error on my code: [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebDAx.png)

I am a beginner, what may be causing this error?

This is my code:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer​ = ​window​.​dataLayer​ || ​​[];​
dataLayer​.​push​({
              'event': 'product_view',
              'ecommerce': {
                'product': {
            'sku': '',
            'name': 'product_name',
            'categories': 'category_name',
            'price': 672,
            }
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remember you can post images as images `![Coherent description of the image](link/to/image)`, which is better than links.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some extra characters that you can't see, the little red dots in your screenshot is `\u200b` characters: **Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)**

Use this instead, I have removed the charcters in this snippet.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'product_view',
  'ecommerce': {
    'product': {
      'sku': '',
      'name': 'product_name',
      'categories': 'category_name',
      'price': 672,
    }
  }
});
```